# Import from List - Batch file

Tags: windows, batch, import, directory-listing

Ok here is the scenario. I am trying to figure out a way to copy users' docs and settings (Favorites, My Documents and Desktop) to a network location as a backup for decommissioned drives. My problem is the variable of the user names `%username%` is only the logged in user so I have opted to export to a list but I do not know the correct way to import those names back in or create the loop. Notice I also would like my destination directory to use the same username. Please notice this is just for the desktop folder so far. Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
md "\\server\share\folder\Downloads\%computername%"
cd documents and settings
dir >> list.txt 

xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\dir >> list.txt\Desktop" "\\server\share\folder\downloads\%computername%\(name from list)" /D/R
```

Comment: If you are able to use Windows Easy Transfer, it affords a nice UI to individually select all the users and the particular special user folders of interest.  Furthermore it zips it up nicely in a special binary file, which is convenient since you're using it as a backup and don't care about viewing the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you loop over your users dirs with something like this?

```
@echo off
md "\\server\share\folder\Downloads\%computername%"
cd documents and settings

for /f %%u in ('dir /b') do (
    xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\Desktop" "\\server\share\folder\downloads\%computername%\%%u" /D/R
```

IMHO no need to use a temp file... (unless you need it for another reason)

Comment: This works great thanks! however i do get a prompt asking if this is a dir or a file. How can i answer that in the script.

Comment: `dir /b /ad` should return you only dirs...

Comment: I added that but continues the prompt. Does \\my servername\tf\POL-5TVK5J1\Administrator\Desktop specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?

Comment: THis is as now@echo off md "\\my server\tf\%computername%" cd documents and settings for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\Desktop" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Desktop" /D/R for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\Favorites" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Favorites" /D/R for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\My Documents" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\My Documents" /D/R %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "c:\Documents and Settings" %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "\\my server\tf\%computername%"

Comment: I added that but continues the prompt. Does \\my servername\tf\POL-5TVK5J1\Administrator\Desktop specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)? Any help getting around the prompt or changes to run the script without copying locally first would be great.

Comment: can you edit your first post with your script? in comments it's barely readable... ;)