# How to answer a prompt in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, prompt

Per [suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/608781/import-from-list-batch-file#comment753223_608960) I added `/ad` to return only dirs, but continue to get prompted. The prompt suggests it wants to know whether to create a file or directory.

How do I automate the answer in a batch script?

This is the prompt:

```
Does \\server\tf\POL-5TVK5J1\Administrator\Desktop specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?
```

Here is my script:

```
@echo off
md "\\my server\tf\%computername%"
cd documents and settings
for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\Desktop" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Desktop" /D /R
for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\Favorites" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Favorites" /D /R
for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\My Documents" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\My Documents" /D /R
for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\Personal" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Personal" /D /R
for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\local settings\application data\Microsoft\Outlook" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Outlook" /D /R
```

Comment: Per what suggestion? I've added the link, but next time you should remember to do so, so as not to confuse people who don't know what you might be referring to.

Comment: forgotten slash in end destination path `"\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Desktop\"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This parameter for xcopy should help:

```
/I    If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
      assumes that destination must be a directory.
```

Comment: Hi, clear directory -> file?)

Comment: @STTR: I couldn't quite understand your comment. Can you ask in a different way? Since he's copying directories, `/i` will help the OP and automatically create directories at the destination, instead of prompting him every time. It's better to use this rather than rely on a trailing backslash.

Comment: THis is it! thanks! I am obviously inexperienced. Thanks so much  Not sure where to add the /i so i went with the trailing backslash and it works like a charm.

Comment: `xcopy /?` says `XCOPY source [destination] [options]`, but I don't think it cares about the order. You can add `/s /d /r /i` all together right after xcopy and before you specify the source and destination dirs, or at the end, as you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

forgotten slash in end destination path `"\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Desktop\"`

`for /f %%u in ('dir /b /ad') do xcopy /s "c:\Documents and Settings\%%u\Desktop" "\\my server\tf\%computername%\%%u\Desktop\" /D /R`